# This code is not running in Linkedin console panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, linkedin-api

This is the code I have written. When I am trying to increase the value of count from 4 to 9 in the if condition, it stop working and leaving with a dozens of errors. This is the code used to sent multiple invites at the same time in  Linkedin->my network

```
var count=1;
var ref;
var ar;
function callmeagain()
{
      $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop:$("body").height()-100
       }, 500);

$("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop:$("body").height()
    }, 500);
if(count===4)
{
        clearInterval(ref);
        $("html,body").animate({
             scrollTop:0
        }, 50);
       ar=document.getElementsByClassName('button-secondary-small');
}
count++;
}
ref=setInterval(callmeagain,1100);
```

After pasting the above code in the console of linkedin->my network wait for some  time until it stops scrolling then paste this code below :

```
for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++)ar[i].click();
```

Now try this same code with changing the condition from count===4 to count===9

Comment: When you run this code, what happens _exactly_? Have you done any debugging? For example if you want the `if` clause to fire, examine what value is in `count` and whether it is an integer.

Comment: Actually what exactly happening is when I am using this code in the console of the linkedin->my network it does every thing that I want that is sending all networks an invitation but when I am changing the condition from count===4 to count===9 or greater than my console is showing me a dozens of error which is not related to my code and my code stops work there can you exactly tell me what is happening and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if this question wasn't just "Please make my code work", but ill try anyways.

Your question states you want:

> to increase the value of count from 4 to 9 it stops working.

I went through your code an organized it so i could see what is going 
on. Heres the Js fiddle I used: https://jsfiddle.net/sovzgadb/4/

Heres the issue:
When `count === 4` you clear your `ref` interval. By clearing the interval you are ensuring the function wont run again on an interval. You need to `setInterval` again after clearing it if you wish to continue running the function every 1100 milliseconds.

For the future, It is easier for people to answer your question when you have investigated the issue instead of just asking for somebody to fix your code.

Hope this helps you!

Edit: Here is the Js code to select all elements by selector with pure javascirpt:

```js
var ar = document.querySelectorAll('ul.mn-pymk-list__cards button.button-secondary-small');
```

Comment: I just mean that when i made a change in condition  from count===4  to count===9 and tried it on the console of linkedin->my network I got so many errors which are not related to my code

Comment: Second thing don't answer the question like the one you have answered if you don't like the question just ignore it.I asked only because I am a beginner.

Comment: Actually what exactly happening is when I am using this code in the console of the linkedin->my network it does every thing that I want that is sending all networks an invitation but when I am changing the condition from count===4 to count===9 or greater than my console is showing me a dozens of error which is not related to my code and my code stops work there can you exactly tell me what is happening and why

Comment: My apologies Shrey. Are all of he errors the same? if so can you paste one of them here?

Comment: @ShreyGarg Or if you can post a screen capture of the errors to your original question that may be more helpful for future people encountering a problem similar to this one.

Comment: I am not eligible for posting photos as my reputation does not meet with the requirements of stack overflow so, here are some of the errors:-

Comment: Actually I have re-edit the code now have a look and please tell me

Comment: Ok Shrey, I just tried your code on Linkedin. The first couple of buttons in `ar` are not the connect buttons that i think you wish to (somewhat spammishly) click. Check out `querySelectorAll` (hhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). That will let you build a CSS selector which very specifically targets the correct connect buttons. A possible selector would be `ul.mn-pymk-list__cards button.button-secondary-small`.

Comment: No difference after using querySelectorAll